# Debugging symbian application using capability that can't be self signed

Tags: qt, symbian, qt-creator, nokia, apptrk

Right now I'm learning Qt, especially QtMobility messaging. I deploy it to S60 FP 2, Nokia E72.

But the application using capability that needed to have non self-signed license. Until now if I need to deploy it to the device, I need to upload the file to https://www.symbiansigned.com/app/page/public/openSignedOnline.do first so the application have an open license.

The problem is, it is not a short way. To deploy it I need to build->compile->upload->email confirmation->download->uninstall old version at phone->install new one -> trying. And it is worse if my internet connection down.

Is there any easier (and hopefully free) way? 
The point is I need to license it, enough for one phone, I'm still learning and have no intention to publish it. The Ovi Publisher need 1 euro payment via credit card, and I don't have any with me.

EDITED:
I just read this
http://wiki.forum.nokia.com/index.php/How_to_guide_for_creating/signing_sis_files
and found out that I used only capabilities that can be used by self-signed. But when I try to use self-signed certificate and try to run it from QtCreator it is giving General-OS-Related Error.
When I tried to install the application manually the application works fine that it isn't need to do open signed things..... -*_*-
So I think the problem is with QtCreator / TRK. Is there any solution that the application can be run using QtCreator?

Edited:
After I installed manually, the TRK then works just fine. -.-" Really I don't understand.
Sorry for the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have a solid answer to this , but yes i have experienced the same issue a lot while using Qt Creator. Most of the time the issue is gone when i either restart windows or restart the phone. Also this issue seems to occur if you disconnect the usb from the phone while debugging.